# Login Failure in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm facing a problem with the login to the application. When the user logs in it checks in the database and if the details matches it returns true else false. Now the point is when some user tries to login it is returning false but the same credentials return true in some other system. I tried switching off firewall also in that system but the problem is same. I'm not able to find out what is the problem here. This issue is very rare. It's a exam application. daily almost 20-30 students takes exam and this issue arises very rarely.

Comment: Have you debug and check whether it uses the same username(or what ever you use to validate user) all the time?

Comment: All the validations are done in the SQL Side and I only tried to login with the user machine using team viewer but It returns false.